# Removing duplicates in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I am trying to remove all the duplicates and only make the original value remain in a nested dictionary. This is my nested dictionary below. In this dictionary, I am trying to check if two names are the same and if they are same, then remove the second and subsequent duplicates. For example: dictionaries 4 and 5 have the same name 'Sasha', so dictionary 5 should be removed.

```
    dict1 = {
1: {'friends': [2],
     'history': [],
     'id': 1,
     'name': 'Fred',
     'date_of_birth': datetime.date(2022, 2, 1)},
 2: {'friends': [1],
     'history': [],
     'id': 2,
     'name': 'Jenny',
     'date_of_birth': datetime.date(2004, 11, 18)},
 3: {'friends': [4],
     'history': [],
     'id': 3,
     'name': 'Jiang',
     'date_of_birth': datetime.date(1942, 9, 16)},
 4: {'friends': [3],
     'history': [],
     'id': 4,
     'name': 'Sasha',
     'date_of_birth': datetime.date(1834, 2, 2)},
 5: {'friends': [6],
     'history': [],
     'id': 5,
     'name': 'Sasha',
     'date_of_birth': datetime.date(1834, 2, 2)},
 6: {'friends': [5],
     'history': [],
     'id': 6,
     'name': 'Amir',
     'date_of_birth': datetime.date(1981, 8, 11)}}
```

I have implemented my solution like this but I don't understand where I am going wrong.

```
temp = []
res = dict()
for key, val in dict1.items():
    if val not in temp:
        temp.append(val)
        res[key] = val

print(pprint.pformat(res))
```

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for-loop, `val` is the inner dictionary and if you look closely, the value of 4 and 5 are different (`"friends"` and `"id"` are different), so it's not dropped. However, since you only need the `"name"` to be the same (not the entire dictionary), you can keep track of the `"name"` instead and keep only unique names:

```
temp = []
res = dict()
for key, val in dict1.items():
    if val['name'] not in temp:
        temp.append(val['name'])
        res[key] = val
```

**Edit:**

If the goal is to "shift" keys as well, you could approach it a little differently by only storing the non-duplicate values in `res`, then `zip` it with the keys of `dict1` to create the output dictionary:

```
temp = set()
res = []
for val in dict1.values():
    if val['name'] not in temp:
        temp.add(val['name'])
        res.append(val)
out = dict(zip(dict1, res))
```

Output:

```
{1: {'friends': [2],
  'history': [],
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'Fred',
  'date_of_birth': datetime.date(2022, 2, 1)},
 2: {'friends': [1],
  'history': [],
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'Jenny',
  'date_of_birth': datetime.date(2004, 11, 18)},
 3: {'friends': [4],
  'history': [],
  'id': 3,
  'name': 'Jiang',
  'date_of_birth': datetime.date(1942, 9, 16)},
 4: {'friends': [3],
  'history': [],
  'id': 4,
  'name': 'Sasha',
  'date_of_birth': datetime.date(1834, 2, 2)},
 5: {'friends': [5],
  'history': [],
  'id': 6,
  'name': 'Amir',
  'date_of_birth': datetime.date(1981, 8, 11)}}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, is there any way to update indices as well in python?. As in making the indice 6 to 5 as the previous 6 has been deleted.

Comment: @Kaarthik I edited the answer. It does what you wanted now.